# Why result of MemoryPoolMXBean.MemoryUsage.getUsed for old generation decrease without mixed GC under G1?

Tags: g1gc

I can sure no mixed GC or full GC happened through GC log, but value of `G1 Old Gen` from `MemoryUsage.getUsed` decreased. From the following picture we can find that the old generation usage repeat grow very slowly and then decrease to a low value(It seems the JVM do a mixed GC).

[image]

So my question is that whether young GC affect old generation usage?